# svnserver in linux option expected

Tags: linux, svn

I am configuring a svn server, but when i try to make a checkout, the prompt shows this error:

```
svn: E200002: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'svn://localhost/heartview'
svn: E200002: /home/factory/svn/repository/heartview/conf/svnserve.conf:20: Option Expected
```

my svnserver.conf file says:

```
[general]

line 20 :anon-access = read
line 21 :auth-access = write
```

Comment: You might be able to get faster answers at serverfault.com. This is kind of a borderline question to be honest; it could be valid on either site.

Answer (score 6):

When we uncomment parameters in `svnserve.conf` during svn server configuration , it leaves a whitespace character before the parameter.  Just remove the whitespace character from the parameters you uncommented  in `svnserve.conf`

```
anon-access = read
auth-access = write
```

This should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem as yours but in different lines and command.

Mine:

```
 password-db = passwd
```

Then I got **Option Expected** error.

I realized that in front of them there was a space.

I removed it then the problem was solved.

Hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think your conf should be this, without those line numbers:

```
[general]

anon-access = read
auth-access = write
```

How did those get in there? Check for other similar problems. Perhaps it's best to start over with a clean new repository.